# list CSS cursor-values supported by the current browser using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to list all possible values for the CSS cursor-property using JavaScript?

I'm looking for something along the lines of

```
var possibleValues = document.getAllPossibleCusorValues();
```

I have done [some testing](http://codepen.io/nils-a/pen/iKnsC) but that's based on a given set of possible cursors from [CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html#cursor-props) and [CSS3-Draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-ui/#cursor)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to MDN (should have known...). But as @kartikluke guessed I'm looking for a way to list all possible values using JavaScript (a bit like `document.getAllPossibleCusorValues()`)

Comment: You should clarify the question by editing the question itself. It now very much looks like a question “Where do I find documentation about the allowed values?”

Comment: I edited the question to reflect my search for a JS-solution & added a link to the CSS3-draft (instead of w3schools)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current authoritative reference on `cursor` property values is [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html#cursor-propsy), as mentioned in the question. There is work in progress to define *CSS Basic User Interface Module Level 3 (CSS3 UI)*, currently as [Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/) (there is a newer Editor’s Draft, but it does not seem to contain additions to the set of values), with some added keywords.

This is just the values currently defined in a specification and in a draft. Browsers may actually support some different set of values. There is probably no direct way to find out that set in JavaScript, which is what the question seems to be, according to a comment.

You can, however, check which values among those in the spec and the draft (or, more generally, in some specific list)  are supported by the browser, by assigning each value to the property and checking whether it really gets that value or remains unchanged. The following code does that. It does not deal with URL values (which are not keywords).

```
<script>
var values = [
'auto', 'default', 'none',
'context-menu', 'help', 'pointer', 'progress', 'wait',
'cell', 'crosshair', 'text', 'vertical-text',
'alias', 'copy', 'move', 'no-drop', 'not-allowed',
'e-resize', 'n-resize', 'ne-resize', 'nw-resize',
's-resize', 'se-resize', 'sw-resize', 'w-resize',
'ew-resize', 'ns-resize', 'nesw-resize', 'nwse-resize',
'col-resize', 'row-resize', 'all-scroll', 'zoom-in', 'zoom-out'
];
var supported = [];
var e = document.createElement('div');
for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  e.style.cursor = values[i];
  if(e.style.cursor === values[i]) {
    supported.push(values[i]); }
}
document.write(supported);
</script>
```

(Testing with newest versions of popular browsers shows that Firefox supports the entire list, and Chrome and IE support all but `zoom-in` and `zoom-out`.)

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) (Hover cursor on list to test)

[developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org) it's a more reliable source than [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the docs for the cursor property here at [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)

```
Formal syntax: [ [ <uri> [<x> <y>]?,]* [ auto | default | none | context-menu | help | pointer | progress | wait | cell | crosshair | text | vertical-text | alias | copy | move | no-drop | not-allowed | e-resize | n-resize | ne-resize | nw-resize | s-resize | se-resize | sw-resize | w-resize | ew-resize | ns-resize | nesw-resize | nwse-resize | col-resize | row-resize | all-scroll | zoom-in | zoom-out | grab | grabbing ] ]
```

I assume you want to list them using Javascript. I'm not sure that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

From MDN [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor), you can have followings value of cursor :

```
auto | default | none | context-menu | help | pointer | progress | wait | cell | crosshair | text | vertical-text | alias | copy | move | no-drop | not-allowed | e-resize | n-resize | ne-resize | nw-resize | s-resize | se-resize | sw-resize | w-resize | ew-resize | ns-resize | nesw-resize | nwse-resize | col-resize | row-resize | all-scroll | zoom-in | zoom-out | grab | grabbing
```